# C#: how to find .DLL and .CS dependecies automatically?

Tags: c#, msbuild

We in our company have Visual Studio project with dozens of *.cs files.
We need to compile each .cs file as separate *.dll.

It's not acceptable to move files to different projects.

I need to programatically collect all actually *used* dependencies for each *.cs file to build it via csc.exe or msbuild, it doesn't mater.

For example: File1.cs depends on File5.cs, File6.cs, File11.cs (all in the same project), also depends on Library1.dll, Library3.dll, Library7.dll

With that information i could call `csc.exe /r:Library1.dll /r:Library3.dll /r:Library7.dll File1.cs File5.cs, File6.cs, File11.cs`

Any suggestions?

Comment: A Source-file never relies on another one, but assemblies do depend on others. I doubt there is a way to get dependencies of a source-code-file.

Comment: It is possible using reflection and whatnot, see e.g. tools like Resharper which are able to remove unneeded dependencies and add missing ones, but it might be hard.

Comment: "We need to compile each .cs file as separate *.dll."   Why?  That sounds nutty.  If you need to this, put each file in a seperate csproj.

Comment: Each .cs file is report. We had one report per project previously but have decided to leave that approach because there were conflicts in sln file when several report developers were adding new reports at the same time in TFS. Also solution become huge and clumsy with hundreds of reports. Each report is pretty small single file so no matter to store it in separate project.

Comment: If the reason is tooling, why not address that? Use TFS properly, or in another way, or use something else?